# The number of binary digits is less than the value

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary

I want a proof that the number of binary digits is less than the value. There is a log relationship $$base_{digits} = \log_2(value) + 1.$$ I can't seem to prove $base_{digits}<value$. Or perhaps using the definition $$n=a_m2^m +\dots+a_02^0.$$ Where $m+1$ is the number of binary digits. We must also recognize that for this inequality to hold $value>2$ where the $value\in\mathbb{W}$.

Comment: The number of bits required to represent zero is one, which exceeds the value zero. The number of bits required to represent one is one, which is no less than the value of one; similarly for two. Seems you need to assume $n\ge3$.

Comment: There was no reason to call "decimal" the value of an integer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, that condition must be included.

Comment: And for $n\ge4$ i.e. $m\ge2,$
$$n\ge 2^m>m+1.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commenters have pointed out, we need to assume we are talking about integers here, and we must assume $n\geq 3$.

After this, we need not use any facts about logarithms or exponents, we can simply observe that incrementation of a number by one can increase its number of binary digits (or for that matter, its digits in any base) by at most one.  Therefore if the result is true for $n=k$, it must hold for $n=k+1$ as well.  Since the result is true for $n=3$, it follows by induction that it is true for all $n\geq 3$.